# Time dependency of interacting Hamiltonian in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Suppose I have a Lagrangian of the form

$$\mathscr{L} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi - m^2\right) - \frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4, $$

which is just an interacting real scalar field. The Hamiltonian of this field should be

$$H = \frac{1}{2} \int d^3\mathbf{x} \; \left( \dot{\phi}^2 + \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi +m^2 \phi^2 +\frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4 \right) .$$ My lecturer said that in Heisenberg picture this Hamiltonian is time dependent and this makes it so the final vacuum and the initial vacuum are different. I understand how this Hamiltonian is time dependent in interaction picture but not how it can be time dependent in Heisenberg picture. After all operators in Heisenberg picture evolve as $O_H (t) = e^{iH(t-t_0)} O_H(t_0) e^{-iH(t-t_0)} $, and the Hamiltonian commutes with itself, so $H_H(t) = H_H(t_0)$. What am I missing?

Comment: I think your teacher is mistaken.

Comment: @mikestone it's entirely possible (and even more likely) that I might be mistaken and took my notes incorrectly even though I'm usually very careful

Comment: Yep, in Heisenberg picture the Hamiltonian is time independent

Comment: Though if your teacher said this not about *interacting* but about *interaction* Hamiltonian he/she is correct

Comment: @OON yeah, that must be it, I misheard what he said. He must have been talking about the potential part of the Hamiltonian $\lambda/4! \phi^4$ and not the full Hamiltonian $H_0+V$. Thanks to you both

Comment: It also may be that in your lectures you discussed the transition to the Heisenberg picture assuming (as often is done) that eigenvectors in the Schrodinger picture are defined as time independent. Then of course in the Heisenberg picture they will get the phase.

Comment: I am pretty sure we always assumed that eigenvectors might get a phase in schrodinger picture because of the "ordinary" time evolution (this is, if they are eigenvectors of the full Hamiltonian)